# Conway's game of life in 3D FPS problems

Tags: webgl, twgl.js

I am trying to implement [conway's game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) in 3D. Basically, I am experimenting it with an extra dimension.

I am instantiating a list of cubes at the start of the game and give each one of them an index that's going to be associated with a logic object where I call [twgl.drawObjectList](https://pastebin.com/yvsgBtaA) if it's alive, else I will skip it within a function that I am using requestAnimationFrame on.

**The problem is** that the FPS drops below 1 when I make a 50*50*50 (125000 cubes) game. Is this normal? Am I doing the correct approach?

Edit:

```
function newGame (xDimV, yDimV, zDimV, gameSelected = false) {
// No game to load
if (!gameSelected) {
    xDim = xDimV;
    yDim = yDimV;
    zDim = zDimV;
} else {
    xDim = gameSelected[0][0].length;
    yDim = gameSelected[0].length;
    zDim = gameSelected.length;
}
myGame = Object.create(game);
myGame.consutructor(xDim , yDim , zDim, gameSelected);
objects = [];
for (var z = 0; z < zDim; z++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < yDim; y++){
        for (var x = 0; x < xDim; x++){

            var uniforms = {
                u_colorMult: chroma.hsv(emod(baseHue + rand(0, 120), 360), rand(0.5,
                                    1), rand(0.5, 1)).gl(),
                u_world: m4.identity(),
                u_worldInverseTranspose: m4.identity(),
                u_worldViewProjection: m4.identity(),
            };

            var drawObjects = [];
            drawObjects.push({
                programInfo: programInfo,
                bufferInfo: cubeBufferInfo,
                uniforms: uniforms,
            });

            objects.push({
                translation: [(x*scale)-xDim*scale/2, (z*scale), (y*scale)-yDim*scale/2],
                scale: scale,
                uniforms: uniforms,
                bufferInfo: cubeBufferInfo,
                programInfo: programInfo,
                drawObject: drawObjects,
                index: [z, y, x],
            });
        }
    }
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

var then = 0;
function render(time) {
time *= 0.001;
var elapsed = time - then;
then = time;

twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.clearColor(255, 255, 0, 0.1);
var fovy = 30 * Math.PI / 180;
var projection = m4.perspective(fovy, gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight, 0.5, 10000);

var eye = [cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ];
var target = [cameraX, cameraY, 10];
var up = [0, 1, 0];

var camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
var view = m4.inverse(camera);
var viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, view);
viewProjection =  m4.rotateX(viewProjection, phi);
viewProjection = m4.rotateY(viewProjection, theta);
targetTimer -= elapsed;

objects.forEach(function(obj) {
    var uni = obj.uniforms;
    var world = uni.u_world;
    m4.identity(world);
    m4.translate(world, obj.translation, world);
    m4.scale(world, [obj.scale, obj.scale, obj.scale], world);
    m4.transpose(m4.inverse(world, uni.u_worldInverseTranspose), uni.u_worldInverseTranspose);
    m4.multiply(viewProjection, uni.u_world, uni.u_worldViewProjection);

    if (myGame.life[obj.index[0]][obj.index[1]][obj.index[2]] === 1) {
        twgl.drawObjectList(gl, obj.drawObject);
    }
});
if (targetTimer <= 0 && !paused) {
    targetTimer = targetChangeInterval / speed;
    myGame.nextGen();
    setGameStatus();
    myGame.resetStatus();
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Impossible to say for sure without seeing a code. I would expect some lag though trying to initialize 125k 3D objects.

Comment: You could profile it to see what's going on during that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

125k cubes is quite a lot. Typical AAA games generally make 1000 to 5000 draw calls total. There are breakdowns on the web of various game engines and how many draw calls they take the generate a frame.

Here's [a talk with several methods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfQ8rKGTVlg). It includes putting all the cubes in one giant mesh and moving them around in JavaScript so they're is effectively one draw call.

If it was me I'd do that and I'd make a texture with one pixel per cube. So for 125k cubes that texture would be like 356x356 though I'd probably choose something more fitting the cube size like 500x300 (since each face slice is 50x50). For each vertex of each cube I'd have an attribute with a UV pointing to a specific pixel in that texture. In other words for the first vertices of the first cube there would be an attribute that UVs that repeats 36 times, in a new UVs for the 2nd cube that repeats 36 times,

```
 attribute vec2 cubeUV;
```

Then I can use the cubeUV to lookup a pixel in the texture whether or not the cube should be on or off

```
 attribute vec2 cubeUV;
 uniform sampler2D lifeTexture;     

 void main() {
   float cubeOn = texture2D(lifeTexture, cubeUV).r;
 }
```

I could clip out the cube pretty easily with

```
   if (cubeOn < 0.5) {
     gl_Position = vec4(2, 2, 2, 1);  // outside clip space
     return;
   }

   // otherwise do the calcs for a cube
```

In this case the cubes don't need to move so all JavaScript has to do each frame is compute life in some `Uint8Array` and then call

```
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, lifeTexture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, width, height, 0,
              gl.LUMINANCE, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, lifeStatusUint8Array);
```

every frame and make one draw call.

Note: You can effectively see examples of this type of shader [here](https://www.vertexshaderart.com/art/Q4dpCbhvWMYfDz5Nb) except that that shdaer is not looking at a texture with *life* running in it, instead it's looking at a texture with 4 seconds of audio data in it. It's also generating the `cubeId` from `vertexId` and generating the cube vertices and normals from `vertexId`.  That would make it slower than putting that data in attributes but it is an example of positioning or drawing cubes based on data coming from a texture.

```js
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 cubeUV;

uniform mat4 u_matrix;
uniform sampler2D u_lifeTex;

varying vec3 v_normal;

void main() {
  float on = texture2D(u_lifeTex, cubeUV).r;
  if (on < .5) {
     gl_Position = vec4(20, 20, 20, 1);
     return;
  }
  gl_Position = u_matrix * position;  
  v_normal = normal;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 v_normal;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(v_normal * .5 + .5, 1);
}
`;

const oneFace = [
  [ -1, -1, ],
  [  1, -1, ],
  [ -1,  1, ],
  [ -1,  1, ],
  [  1, -1, ],
  [  1,  1, ],
];

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");

// compiles shaders, links program, looks up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

const cubeSize = 50;
const texBuf = makeCubeTexBuffer(gl, cubeSize);
const tex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {
  src: texBuf.buffer,
  width: texBuf.width,
  format: gl.LUMINANCE,
  wrap: gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE,
  minMag: gl.NEAREST,
});

const arrays = makeCubes(cubeSize, texBuf);
// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001; // seconds
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  //gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  
  const fov = Math.PI * .25;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const zNear = .01;
  const zFar  = 1000;
  const projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
  
  const radius = cubeSize * 2.5;
  const speed = time * .1;
  const position = [
     Math.sin(speed) * radius, 
     Math.sin(speed * .7) * radius * .7, 
     Math.cos(speed) * radius,
  ];
  const target = [0, 0, 0];
  const up = [0, 1, 0];
  const camera = m4.lookAt(position, target, up);
  
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);
  
  const mat = m4.multiply(projection, view);

  // do life
  // (well, randomly turn on/off cubes)
  for (let i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
     texBuf.buffer[Math.random() * texBuf.buffer.length | 0] = Math.random() > .5 ? 255 : 0;
  }
  
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.LUMINANCE, texBuf.width, texBuf.height,
                0, gl.LUMINANCE, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texBuf.buffer);
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program)

  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);

  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    u_matrix: mat,
    u_lifeTex: tex,
  });

  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);

// generate cubes
function makeCube(vertOffset, off, uv, arrays) {
  const positions = arrays.position;
  const normals = arrays.normal;
  const cubeUV = arrays.cubeUV;
  
  for (let f = 0; f < 6; ++f) {
    const axis = f / 2 | 0;    
    const sign = f % 2 ? -1 : 1;
    const major = (axis + 1) % 3;
    const minor = (axis + 2) % 3;

    for (let i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
      const offset2 = vertOffset * 2;
      const offset3 = vertOffset * 3;
      positions[offset3 + axis ] = off[axis]  + sign;
      positions[offset3 + major] = off[major] + oneFace[i][0];
      positions[offset3 + minor] = off[minor] + oneFace[i][1];
      normals[offset3 + axis ] = sign;
      normals[offset3 + major] = 0;
      normals[offset3 + minor] = 0;
      
      cubeUV[offset2 + 0] = uv[0]; 
      cubeUV[offset2 + 1] = uv[1]; 
      ++vertOffset;
    }
  }
  return vertOffset;
}

function makeCubes(size, texBuf) {
  const numCubes = size * size * size;
  const numVertsPerCube = 36;
  const numVerts = numCubes * numVertsPerCube;
  const slicesAcross = texBuf.width / size | 0;
  const arrays = {
    position: new Float32Array(numVerts * 3),
    normal: new Float32Array(numVerts * 3),
    cubeUV: new Float32Array(numVerts * 2),
  };
  
  let spacing = size * 1.2;
  let vertOffset = 0;
  for (let z = 0; z < size; ++z) {
    const zoff = (z / (size - 1) * 2 - 1) * spacing;
    for (let y = 0; y < size; ++y) {
      const yoff = (y / (size - 1) * 2 - 1) * spacing;
      for (let x = 0; x < size; ++x) {
        const xoff = (x / (size - 1) * 2 - 1) * spacing;
        const sx = z % slicesAcross;
        const sy = z / slicesAcross | 0;
        const uv = [
          (sx * size + x + 0.5) / texBuf.width, 
          (sy * size + y + 0.5) / texBuf.height,
        ];
        vertOffset = makeCube(vertOffset, [xoff, yoff, zoff], uv, arrays);
      }
    }
  }
  arrays.cubeUV = {
    numComponents: 2,
    data: arrays.cubeUV,
  };
  return arrays;
}

function makeCubeTexBuffer(gl, cubeSize) {
  const numCubes = cubeSize * cubeSize * cubeSize;
  const maxTextureSize = Math.min(gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE), 2048);
  const maxSlicesAcross = maxTextureSize / cubeSize | 0;
  const slicesAcross = Math.min(cubeSize, maxSlicesAcross);
  const slicesDown = Math.ceil(cubeSize / slicesAcross);
  const width = slicesAcross * cubeSize;
  const height = slicesDown * cubeSize;
  const buffer = new Uint8Array(width * height);
  return {
    buffer: buffer,
    slicesAcross: slicesAcross,
    slicesDown: slicesDown,
    width: width,
    height: height,
  };
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

hoiested from the comments below, using a big merged mesh appears to be 1.3x faster than using instanced drawing. Here's 3 samples

1. [big mesh using texture uvs](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/r3v7kqv7/) (same as above)
2. [instanced using texture uvs](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/zxL7tg63/) (less data, same shader)
3. [instanced no texture](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/thskx0x2/) (no texture, life data is in buffer/attribute)

For me, on my machine #1 can do 60x60x60 cubes (216000) at 60fps whereas both #2 and #3 only get 56x56x56 cubes (175616) at 60fps. Of course other GPUs/system/browsers might be different.

Comment: Still though, why not use instancing? Why make one giant mesh ( cube x N ) instead of one small mesh and an attribute (cube + N )? I'm not sure if i understand what happens with the attributes. My understanding is that you only have the data that you put in there. For example, instead of doing the id's as 1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2.... etc, you'd only have one value per entire instance?

Comment: Because instancing is slow. AFAICT few GPUs actually support it in hardware. Instead you're just saving the overhead of the draw call between you and the driver but the driver is still starting and stopping (or queuing) one GPU draw call per instance. So you get a few percent speed up (just the call overhead) whereas with a big mesh it does actually become one GPU draw call and you get a HUGE speed increase.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense.

Comment: Is this an esoteric feature? Is it expected for more gpus to support it?

Comment: Actually let me take that back. That was my experience in the past but I just tested it and at a quick glance, at least on my current GPU (at 2015 MPB) it seems it's not as bad as I remember with [big mesh](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/r3v7kqv7/) vs [instanced](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/zxL7tg63/). I upped cubeSize until the fps went below 60. For bigmesh I got 60, for instanced I got 56. That's 216000 cubes for big mesh, 175616 for Instanced which puts big mesh at 1.29x faster? Of course I should really make the canvas 1x1 pixel to test vertex shader speed.

Comment: I've been making a module/patch for three.js based on this. http://dusanbosnjak.com/test/webGL/three-instanced-mesh/webgl_instanced_mesh.html it definitely improved the performance, but it might be worth testing against just a merged mesh.

Comment: Big mesh still faster if i understand this correctly, just not order of magnitude?

Comment: There are other advantages to instanced over a merge mesh. It's easier to update one instance with instanced. With a merged mesh you have to update every vertex of an instance unless you indirect through a texture but then there's the overhead of texture fetch in the shader that might make it slower so it really depends on what you're trying to do. I should try that one to.

Comment: The dreaded texture fetch overhead :) I know it's not a good thing, just never figured out how to actually measure it. Is there some math that could roughly compare it to something, like 1 fetch = N normalizations or something like that? The idea here is to update one pixel, instead of X vertices. This update should be the same as updating one attribute when instancing, except for the fetch overhead?

Comment: Ok well I made [another instanced sample that doesn't use a texture fetch](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/thskx0x2/) but it gets the same perf as with texture fetch so at least in this case big mesh is 1.3x faster. For textures I think you just have to try it. Also if you can organize the data so fetches are semi-linear or near each other so you don't thrash the texture cache. Random texture fetches will kill perf.

Comment: And yes, update one pixel, each instance has UV to point to that pixel (or an id that can be used to calc the UV to that pixel).

Comment: I wouldn't implement it in Javascript anyway. consider Blazor (wasm) solution or use the GPU shaders.. see Game of life in shadertoy https://www.shadertoy.com/view/4tVfzh https://www.davidguida.net/conways-game-of-life-with-blazor/

Answer (score 0):

The fps drop is coming from two things most likely:

1. The overhead of doing 125k matrix operations each tick.
2. The overhead of doing 125k drawcalls.

You can look into instancing
 http://blog.tojicode.com/2013/07/webgl-instancing-with.html?m=1

And possibly move the matrix stuff into a shader

Comment: I'm pretty confident instancing will not help

Comment: Why not? Shouldn't issuing less draw calls be faster?